# Android: TextView with stdout

Tags: android, stdout

Day 1 with Android app development. So please excuse my (maybe) stupid question: How can I put `stdout/stderr` of my application to a `TextView`?

Comment: There is no stdout/stderr in Java. Why do you want to use such things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you wish to redirect the output sent to **System.out** with **System.out.println()** to be displayed in your EditText. To achieve that:

1. Define an EditText in the layout of your Activity or Fragment:

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_stdout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:singleLine="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

2. In the **onCreate()** or **onCreateView()** method write the following code after setting / inflating your layout:

```
    //Set your layout with setContentView() or inflate it if in fragment

    final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_stdout);

    System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {

        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        @Override public void write(int oneByte) throws IOException {
            outputStream.write(oneByte);

            editText.setText(new String(outputStream.toByteArray()));
        }
    }));

    //Testing the System.out stream
    System.out.println("Test");
    System.out.println("Test 2");
```

This will write all your output made with **System.out.println()** to the EditText.